# Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 LTS + skystar 2 express hd

Tags: drivers

Dears 
i want to install skystar 2 express hd driver in Ubuntu server 14.04 , i tired from searching in internet i did not see topic helps me

please i need to install skystar 2 express hd in Ubuntu server

and this is a card picture

http://www.satavto.by/soft/skystar_2exphd/sx_01.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The manufacturer does not provide Linux support, applications or drivers, so you will need to rely on the drivers, if provided, in the Linux kernel and Linux-supported programs like [MythTV](http://mythtv.org) to use the card.

Check out linuxtv.org for more information. In particular,
http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/TechniSat
http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Supported_Hardware

Based on my quick reads of the support, this card is likely supported or there are Linux drivers available if it is not supported natively in the kernel.

Comment: Greetings to you
Dear 
Kindly could you just give me step by step how to install driver?

Comment: @AliJassim Have you tried using the card? Install the card in the computer and run `lspci` in a Terminal session; if it properly displays the card information, chances are good that driver support is already in the kernel and no additional driver is required.

Comment: Dear Douggro this is output of command lspci 


02:00.0 Multimedia controller: Philips Semiconductors SAA7160 (rev 03)
Subsystem: Device 1ae4:0700
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
Memory at fe700000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
Capabilities: [40] MSI: Enable- Count=1/32 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [50] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [74] Power Management version 2
Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=50 <?>
Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0000 Rev=0 Len=088 <?>

so please tell me is that mean work or not

Comment: @AliJassim It would appear not. I would suggest you follow the links I provided for learning how to install the relevant driver for the card. You may also need to do some Google searching to aid in your getting the proper driver.